# vSphere, add existing HDD to VM via API(govmomi)

Tags: go, vmware, vsphere

I am try to add existing HDD from one virtual machine to other.
I use golang and this api: https://github.com/vmware/govmomi

At first i get disks from source vm like this:

```
for _, device := range devices {
        currentDeviceLabel := device.GetVirtualDevice().DeviceInfo.GetDescription().Label
        if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(currentDeviceLabel), "hard disk"){
        disks = append(disks, device)
    }    
return disks
```

And then i trying to add received disk to other VM:

```
func addDisk(vm *object.VirtualMachine, disk types.BaseVirtualDevice) {

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    spec := types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec{

        DeviceChange : []types.BaseVirtualDeviceConfigSpec {

            &types.VirtualDeviceConfigSpec{

                Operation: types.VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperationAdd,
                FileOperation: types.VirtualDeviceConfigSpecFileOperationCreate,
                Device: disk,
            },

        },
    }

    result, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, spec)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("err: %s", err.Error()))

    }
```

I get error from vSphere:

```
Cannot complete the operation because the file or folder [xxxxx] xxxxx/xxxxx.vmdk already exists
```

What i am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer here: https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/issues/790

Working code:

```
spec := types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec{}
config := &types.VirtualDeviceConfigSpec{
    Device:    disk,
    Operation: types.VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperationAdd,
}
spec.DeviceChange = append(spec.DeviceChange, config)

result, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, spec)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("err: %s", err.Error()))

}
```